# Float Division in C acting weird?

Tags: c

simple question I assume, but I just stumbled across this:

```
float y=2+2/3;
```

Output: `2`

How come float cannot process 2/3?
My guess is that float interprets 2/3 as integers.
But how come it accepts 2 in the beginning?

Comment: The type of the left hand operand of `=` has nothing whatsoever to with which types that will be used when calculating all sub expressions on the right side of `=`. It merely tells in which type to store the final result once all calculations are done.

Answer (score 2):

That's integer division. You're basically computing:

```
float y = 2 + (2 / 3);
float y = 2 + (0    );
float y = 2;
```

Try:

```
float y = 2 + 2.0 / 3;
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, but how come it allows int numbers such as 2, but not 2/3? Is this just for division? Or does the same happen with multiplication & modulo?

Comment: This. C reads lines from right to left, so it does not know it is supposed to be float until the calculation is already done.

Comment: @Joel Yes, it also holds true for multiplication and modulus.

Comment: @jpa and Tim, thx! Off to the exam! Just a small thing i noticed this morning.

Answer (score 1):

```
float y = 2 + (float)2 / 3;
```

Just typecast, it will also work.